# How to make slide-in-up animation for $state.go functionality in ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework

I want to make animation "slide-in-up" for one of my states.
And as I see it's imposible or I don't know how to do that.
Does anybody know how to do that?

I did smth. like this:

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">    
    <title>Tabs Example</title>
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-in-up"></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab" animation="slide-in-up"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>         

      </ion-tabs>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view animation="slide-in-up" title="Home">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view animation="slide-in-up" title="Facts">
        <ion-content class="padding">          
          <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
          <p><a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home">Home</a></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>        

  </body>
</html>
```

And JS like this:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
        }
      }
    });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Have no idea why.

Comment: Did you able to find any solution for this ?

Comment: it seems like `slide-in-up` was removed post 0.9.27 ! https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/833